# Is there a way to prevent a subset of Jenkins projects to run in parallel?

Tags: jenkins

I have some Jenkis projects that shouldn't be ran in parallel. Is it possible to configure that?

I could off course turn off parallel builds, but it's only needed for those subset of projects.

Comment: I haven't actually used any of these plugins but [Build Blocker](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Build+Blocker+Plugin), [Throttle Concurrent Builds](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Throttle+Concurrent+Builds+Plugin) or [Exclusion Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Exclusion-Plugin) look like they could help you.

Comment: How about selecting the option "Build after other projects are built" ? would that not help ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check "Block build if certain jobs are running" on those jobs. 
This option is available at least at "free-style software project" and "maven2/3 project" types.

Comment: Used https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Throttle+Concurrent+Builds+Plugin